# How to integrate unmounted volumes to my ubuntu system?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, disk-management

I am installing Ubuntu (also on Ubunut currently). I have ubuntu installed in a space of 153.7gb. I have a hard disk space of 1 tb. I want to make one volume and install ubuntu. How do I do that?

[Screenshot showing disk space from disk usage analyser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lujtN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the appropriate option in the "Installation type" dialog of the Ubuntu installation program. One of the options is "Erase disk and install Ubuntu". That option will erase the entire disk and create one volume where Ubuntu will be installed, so this is the option you currently are asking for.

It is always possible to customize partitioning and installation fully to your liking by selecting the "Something else" option. This is for more advanced users, that then can edit the partitioning on the drives and decide which partition should be used.